# Salesforce Community Audience Error

Tags: community-builder

Good afternoon.
I am getting an error when I try to create an audience in the community.
The error is displayed at the top of the page (as shown in the image below) and I can't create the audience:

[image]

Error:

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'some' of undefined] Callback failed: serviceComponent://ui.communities.components.aura.components.setup.audienceEditor.AudienceCustomEditorController/ACTION$getExistingSavedCriteria Failing descriptor: {markup://communitySetup:audienceCustomEditor}
```

Comment: I tried this on Firefox browser and couldn't replicate the error message. Can you try from Firefox and see? Also, please provide the criteria you are using to create the audience.

Comment: Is this in a Spring 20 or a Summer 20 environment?

Comment: I found the solution. There was an audience that, for some reason, was called (disabled). I can't say if it was because of Spring 20. But because this audience exists, it was not possible to create any other one. @Folkert